# Is an Elastic Load Balacing target group a logical construct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am fairly confused by what the Load Balancer Target group is because when the target type is Lambda, in the Lambda function's resource policy, you allow the Target group to invoke it i.e. source of invocation.

What exactly in this logical target group is invoking the Lambda function? If the Target Group is only a logical construct, how is it invoking my Lambda function? The resource policy is as follows:

```
"Sid": "AWS-ALB_Invoke-Tg-lambda-3e9809d3ca4f31a5",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
  "Service": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXX:function:castings-bay",
"Condition": {
  "ArnLike": {
    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXX5:targetgroup/Tg-lambda/3e9809d3ca4f31a5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target group its a **resource**, and a resource in AWS [is](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html#resource-groups-intro):

> In AWS, a resource is **an entity that you can work with**. Examples include an Amazon EC2 instance, an AWS CloudFormation stack, or an Amazon S3 bucket.

Its a very vague definition, and you can put almost everything under it. But I think the real nature of the TG is irrelevant, and how exactly it is implemented in AWS it is **not officially shared by AWS**. It could be a process withing an ALB software, or some intermediary daemon between ALB and your own resources. What matter is that it is a resource (i.e. entity you can work with) and that it has ARN. Whatever it is physically on the backend, it is invoking your lambda function and you must allow for it.

Comment: this makes sense. Thank you.